# Title update in the plots as per the variable passed in function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I call the function individually with a data frame and a particular column directly, the function behaves as expected and the plot's title gets updated when every new variable passed to the function, but when you try to call the function from another function and the plots titles doesn't get updated Instead of the variable name "NA".

I am unable to fix this issue? Can anyone help me understand and fix this issue?

[image]

```
    plot_2 = function(df, xin, ...){
 
 plot1 = ggplot(df , aes(xin, fill = DEATH_EVENT))+
 geom_histogram(...)+
 labs(title = paste(strsplit(deparse(xin),"$", 1)[[1]][2]," during heart attack and consequences"),y = "Count", x = strsplit(deparse(xin),"$", 1)[[1]][2])+
 theme(legend.position = "top")+
 scale_fill_discrete(name = "Deaths due to heart attack", labels = c("No", "Yes"))+
 theme_dark()

 plot2 = ggplot(df, aes(DEATH_EVENT, xin))+
 geom_violin(alpha = 0.5, aes(color = DEATH_EVENT))+
 geom_jitter(alpha = 0.3, aes(color = DEATH_EVENT))+
 labs(title = paste(strsplit(deparse(xin),"$", 1)[[1]][2]," during heart attack and   consequences"), y = strsplit(deparse(xin),"$", 1)[[1]][2], x = "Deaths due to heart attack")+ # To give labels to the plot
 scale_x_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes"))+ # Specified the names of the levels of x axis ticks.
 coord_flip()+ # Flipped the axes
 theme_light()
  
return(ggarrange(plot1,plot2, nrow = 2)) # To get the plots in single window having 1 column and 2 rows

} #plot_num


summary_predictors3 = function(df, xin, group, ...){
  
  summary_expl_variable_and_plot = list()
  class(summary_expl_variable_and_plot) = "summary_stats"
  
   if(is.factor(xin) == FALSE){
  
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$plot = plot_2(df, xin, ...)
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$mean = tapply(xin, group, mean)
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$median = tapply(xin, group, FUN=median)
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$Q1 = tapply(xin, group, FUN=quantile, 0.25)
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$Q3 = tapply(xin, group, FUN=quantile, 0.75)
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$IQR = summary_expl_variable_and_plot$Q1 - 
   summary_expl_variable_and_plot$Q3
  
   
   invisible(summary_expl_variable_and_plot)

   else{
    
    summary_expl_variable_and_plot$plot = plot_categorical_response(df, xin)
    invisible(summary_expl_variable_and_plot)

  }
    
  }

print.summary_stats <- function(variable){

  if(length(variable) > 1){

    print(variable$plot)
     
  } #if
  
  else print(variable$plot)

s = summary_predictors3(df= heart,heart$age, heart$DEATH_EVENT) # This doenst update the plots title

plot_2(heart, heart$age) # But if I call the function directly, it works fine
```

Comment: I answered and hope it was what you are after because your example is complex and we cannot reproduce as we don't have the data. It would better to use `reprex` and reduce complexity. Best

Answer (score 0):

I would embrace `rlang` and do something like this:
Where the bare names is first converted to a quosure that we fist evaluate in the context of the data.frame with the `!!` operator. And in a second time as a string to use it in the title.
hope this heps

```r
library(ggplot2)

curly_title <- function(df, xin) {
  xin <- enquo(xin)
  ggplot(df, aes(x = !!xin)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    labs(title = paste("hist of", rlang::as_name(xin)))
}
curly_title(mtcars, mpg)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>